# I am trying to fetch the emails between given date range using gmail API with OAuth 2.0. Why it does not give the proper output?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

Below is the code

```
import datetime
import os.path
import pickle
import json
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Define the scope and credentials file path
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'

def get_emails_info(after_date, before_date):
    # Load or create credentials
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Build the Gmail service
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

   # Format the dates as per Gmail API requirements
    after_date_str = after_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    before_date_str = before_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

    # Construct the search filter with the date range
    search_filter = f"after:{after_date_str} before:{before_date_str}"
    # Retrieve the emails using Gmail API
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=search_filter).execute()
    messages = results.get('messages', [])

    # Retrieve the email titles
    email_info = []
    for message in messages:
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
        subject = [header['value'] for header in msg['payload']['headers'] 
        if header['name'] == 'Subject'][0]
        email_info.append(subject)

    # Return the count of emails and their titles
    return len(email_info), email_info

   # Specify the date for which you want to retrieve the email count and titles
   after_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 15)
   before_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 16)

   # Call the function to get the email count and titles
   email_count, email_titles = get_emails_info(after_date, before_date)
 
   print("Email titles:")
   for title in email_titles:
    print("\n",title)
```

In output, it eliminates the initial emails of date 15th July and gives the initials few emails of date 16th July. What output exactly I want by this query is all the emails received on 15th July only.

Just in case someone wants to try, here is the link for [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

Can anyone answer it please..